# Writing a Binary String to a file

Tags: python, file-io, bit

I am writing a huffman encoding program to compress a text file. I converted the text file to its huffman encoded value, and I need to write it to a file. I am currently using the python "BitVector" module, but it is far too slow when reading and writing from/to a file. Are there any other ways of doing this(preferably much faster)?

Thanks.

Comment: "far too slow"?  What does that mean?  How many bits are you writing?  How long is it taking?

Comment: Does it exhibit this same slowness when writing to standard output? How about when just turning stuff into internal strings?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [struct package](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) from the python standard library.